# No 'Create DNS Zone' button in Networking Tab

Tags: amazon-lightsail

I am trying to create a new website on Amazon Lightsail.

I followed the tutorials and now I am at where I should create the DNS Zones. The tutorial says to go to the LightSail Console > Networking > Create DNS Zone. But I don't see that button.

Has anything recently got amended on LightSail because Amazon's tutorials still say to find that button under the Networking tab.

https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/articles/lightsail-how-to-create-dns-entry#lightail-create-a-dns-zone

[image: Lightsail Networking Tab]

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same problem. I found the mistake I made. You should not enter the networking tab of a individual instance but the networking tab of the main console page.

For simlicity its' link is here : [Main Networking Tab](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/webapp/home/networking) and as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I spent lots of time looking for the same thing. This is how I got it to work.

1. Go to https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/webapp/home/instances
2. Left side choose **Domains and DNS**
3. CLick on create **DNS Zone button** found on page and follow aws documentation